# Meteor can't install accounts-ui after update

Tags: meteor, meteorite

After I update meteor to 0.8.0, I can't install accounts-ui
Is that my problem or others have the problem too? What should I do?

JubydeMacBook-Air:test juby$ mrt add accounts-ui

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/project.js:225
          throw("Package named " + pkgName + " doesn't exist in your meteor in
                                           ^
Package named accounts-ui doesn't exist in your meteor installation, smart.json, or on atmosphere

Thank for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [meteorite](https://atmospherejs.com/docs/installing) installed: `npm install -g meteorite`

If you have previously added the `accounts-ui` package remove it with `mrt add accounts-ui` then add it back with `mrt add accounts-ui`.

If you still can't add accounts-ui, make sure it was actually removed from your `.meteor/packages` file.

You can then launch the app with `mrt` from the app root directory.

Hope that helps.